# Is there a difference between this.foo = bar and Object.defineProperties(this

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to rewrite some Javascript to make it more easily updatable but then also to convert it to Typescript.

I've seen a few examples of code like this and wondered if I'm missing something here...

For example...

```
class Foo {
  constructor({ name, title }) {
    this.name = name;
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      title: { value: title }
    }
  }
}
```

There isn't anything else in the `definedProperties` object other than the value. So if I was to rewrite this to...

```
class Foo {
  constructor({ name, title }) {
    this.name = name;
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

...does that change anything in the way the code works at all?

I'm just worried that I'm missing something obvious here and didn't want to break it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty? Yes, they are different. Find out why the `title` property was defined with different attributes than the `name` property before changing it.

Comment: @Bergi yes, but perhaps I missed something with it? I couldn't seem to see anything in there that would suggest there is any difference here? Which makes me wonder if I'm missing somewthing as why would the original person who wrote this have written it in this way.

Comment: Please tell us what you learned from that page so we can tell whether you're missing something :-)

Comment: @Bergi I update my comment. Thanks

Comment: The difference is that `name` is a configurable, enumerable, and writable data property, whereas the `title` data property is neither of those. As for why the author of the code did this, we cannot tell - ask them, or go through all usages of `Foo` instances in your code and check where it would make a difference.